# LINUX Shell commands cat and grep

Tags: linux, shell

I am a windows user having basic idea about LINUX and i encountered this command:

```
cat countryInfo.txt | grep -v "^#" >countryInfo-n.txt
```

After some research i found that cat is for concatenation and grep is for regular exp search (don't know if i am right) but what will the above command result in (since both are combined together) ?

Thanks in Advance.

EDIT: I am asking this as i dont have linux installed. Else, i could test it.

Comment: BTW, if you want to know what a Linux command is doing, type `man <command>` in Google. You'll get the "man" (manual) pages for the commands which explains what the command does and what its parameters mean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short answer: it removes all lines starting with a `#` and stores the result in `countryInfo-n.txt`.

Long explanation:

`cat countryInfo.txt` reads the file `countryInfo.txt` and streams its content to standard output.

`|` connects the output of the left command with the input of the right command (so the right command can read what the left command prints).

`grep -v "^#"` returns all lines that do *not* (`-v`) match the regex `^#` (which means: line starts with `#`).

Finally, `>countryInfo-n.txt` stores the output of `grep` into the specified file.

Answer (score 5):

It will remove all lines starting with `#` and put the output in countryInfo-n.txt

Answer (score 4):

This command would result in removing lines starting with `#` from the file `countryInfo.txt` and place the output in the file `countryInfo-n.txt`.

This command could also have been written as

```
grep -v "^#" countryInfo.txt > countryInfo-n.txt
```

See [Useless Use of Cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).